# Allow user to draw circle on the map with radius that they entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

What I have in mind is an input box where the user first enters the radius. Then on a button right beside it to add a draggable circle onto the map.

I've tried the `DrawingMode` in Google Map V3. It ignored that radius setting.

```
var map;
var pos;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    scaleControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl:false,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

function setCurrentLocation(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);
     map.setCenter(pos);
})}


setCurrentLocation();

function drawCircle(){
        var draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: pos,
        radius: 200,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map})}


$( "#addcircle" ).click(function() {
  drawCircle();
});
```

I have tried to use the above method. But it seems like the variable `pos` is not valid in the `drawCircle` function.

```
$( "#addcircle" ).click(function() {
  drawCircle();
});
```

this portion is related to a specific button that once clicked it is supposed to add the circle.

```
function setCurrentLocation(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);
     map.setCenter(pos);

     function drawCircle(){
        var draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: pos,
        radius: 200,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map})}
        ;
        drawCircle();

})}
```

If i change the code to test the `pos`, this works. The `pos` coordinates being actually sent to the circle are valid.

But I can't get the function to work once I've placed the `drawCircle();` withing the button click handler.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Or perhaps look at [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_changeCircleRadius.html)

Comment: sorry, for the lack of code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`
i mean why you don't check console.log(position.coords) inside setCurrentLocation() make sure you are sending the right object "pos" into the circle

or simply assign direct position object into the map : new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798) make sure every thing ok

Comment: 'Coordinates {speed: null, heading: null, altitudeAccuracy: null, accuracy: 70, altitude: null…}
accuracy: 70
altitude: null
altitudeAccuracy: null
heading: null
latitude: 1.4383010999999999
longitude: 103.79765259999999
speed: null
__proto__: Coordinates
constructor: function Coordinates() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object'


Here is the what I get from the console log. Is this right things to send in pos?

Or how do i change it so it send in just the coords?

Comment: `function setCurrentLocation(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);
     map.setCenter(pos);
  
  function drawCircle(){
  var draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: pos,
        radius: 200,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map})}
  ;
  drawCircle();
  
})}
`
I change the code to test the pos, this works.